# "Сровнять с землей" или "сравнять с землей"?

Tags: орфография

Подобный вопрос может возникнуть только у такого параноидального скептика, как я. Всем же нормальным людям очевидно, что с землей можно только ***сровнять***. Оттого только более удивительным кажется факт периодического употребления ***а*** в корне ([Национальный корпус русского языка](http://search.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&mydocsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&text=lexform&mode=main&sort=gr_tagging&lang=ru&nodia=1&req=%F1%F0%E0%E2%ED%FF%F2%FC+%F1+%E7%E5%EC%EB%E5%E9), [Словарь русских синонимов](http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/dic_synonims/265284/срыть)).
Как это понять?

Comment: Noir,там комментарии закончились. Все! Получилось. Огромное вам спасибо. Та, первая ссылка, оказывается, не работала. Поэтому и гиперссылка не сработала.

Comment: >Огромное вам спасибо.

Ах да не стоит...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Правильно: сровнять с землей, то есть всю поверхность сделать РОВНОЙ,  гладкой , также: заровнять яму, ровнять клумбы, разровнять, уровнять  площадку, выровненное поле.

Чтобы объяснить встречающийся вариант "сравнять с землей", уместно вспомнить о существовании слова "уровень" - это  условная горизонтальная линия или плоскость, являющаяся границей высоты чего-л., например: Быть на одном уровне с планкой. Окно расположено на уровне плеч. Ласточки летели на уровне крыш.

Выражение "сравнять с землей", вероятно,  восходит к следующему значению: "разрушить (город) до основания" - это приравнять уровень его территории к уровню территории окружающей местности.

Comment: Стало быть, возможны оба варианта?

Comment: Думаю, что для устойчивого выражения правилен один общепринятый вариант - "сровнять с землей". Но можно понять ход мыслей тех людей, которые пишут "сравнять с землей".  К примеру: уровнять площадку-  уравнять крестьян в правах с другими сословиями, то есть при наличии предлога С чаще используется корень РАВН.

Comment: Благодарю Вас, мне необходимо было авторитетное мнение.

Comment: Данный ответ меня несколько удивил. Да, в русском языке есть как слово "сровнять", так и слово "сравнять". Но в устойчивом сочетании  "сравнять с землей" (в значении "уничтожить") испокон веков использовалось именно слово "сравнять".

Answer (score 1):

Глаголы сравнять и сровнять часто путают. Глагол сравнять используется в значении " сделать равным, приравнять", глагол же сровнять"  совершенного вида и означает " сделать ровным, выровнять" .Именно этот глагол используется в устойчивом выражении "сровнять с землей".  То же самое в словаре на Грамота.ру.
[Здесь](http://yandex.ru/clck/jsredir?from=yandex.ru%3Byandsearch%3Bweb%3B%3B&text=&etext=414.RBYJnwZLT3skxkN5e5Ij5MhdFX9N8-T56QP4JIoiS3H-h1OyHcA6miMYW5LZqmb_R8a1-I3_xsQSc5ybAvnrD-HKJRP28qCyW5hYhIL_7pHYUeCK98f_8X_Fl3RliiDQfCudzRu8jfUl133pWKQDsTcJrPHFDeLA9cZcRusdZhWxGzQrLEj-ocTpi9b0dFHi6ptezVpiFPghyVcUyDdOOVj324GmpjUrISp1_7V_ioxNAIIM2sZxZ1ao1lOySfGA.29c21fd623c533609101ba5acf2362440267340e&uuid=&state=AiuY0DBWFJ4ePaEse6rgeAjgs2pI3DW99KUdgowt9XsGes-COYeAtjuEaMUoBSHPVXBszUvmGGoQ7JXzabAkRIXUmWyrZzAmfWd4X5QIz-sNqukirEPaRhJt9LCYXt3JGp0o6lXq4-KJjPgKGE-I41yt3xkHrZhvniFvC2ItO19JkvYGfF2vtO2IRmSbrIiqM3eSe0u5TJ22P0FRblV9nw&data=UlNrNmk5WktYejR0eWJFYk1Ldmtxb0s5S19SeXU0eWZtVXpZX05GZENnQ1VtQ3k3U3RneFFJQ0pCMDNGa3JvSnhQR2pVaU9pdFRUeWtCTDQwQmpRNnVOcHpZd3d4dV9KMTQzNlV5T0phZkxOTG1INjkzMEk0UQ&b64e=2&sign=dcd0a1cd4992673e036a28e6a5ee46ec&keyno=0&l10n=ru&cts=1407869339705&mc=4.2133809688423405)

Comment: Извиняюсь за длинную ссылку.Так и научился делать короткие.

Comment: Если Вы используете ВКонтакте, то я могу предложить Вам вот такой сервис: vk.com/cc

Comment: Подобными сервисами я пользовался, но ссылка почему-то не срабатывала. И читал я, и здесь объясняли, - тщетно! Пока на практике не увижу, не смогу сделать.

Comment: @Серж, если Вы хотите вставить гиперссылку, для этого Вам достаточно заключить фрагмент текста, который Вы хотите сделать текстовой нагрузкой гиперссылки, в квадратные скобки, а адрес веб-страницы — в круглые, не оставляя пробела между закрывающей квадратной и открывающей круглой скобками: [текстовая нагрузка, собственно текст гиперссылки, который будет выделен синим цветом на странице сайта] (адрес веб-страницы).

Comment: Ноир, спасибо, текст получился. Но ссылка не работает.

Comment: Гиперссылка не работает, а ссылка, на основе которой первая была создана, набранная в адресной строке, работает?

Comment: Да, та работает. Могу прежнюю обратно сделать.Ту, длинную.