# Сровнять с землёй или всё-таки сравнять с землёй?

Tags: орфография

В устойчивом выражении "сровнять с землёй" в глаголе "сровнять" пишется буква -о-. Однако действительно ли нельзя сказать "сделать город равным земле", то есть уравнять уровень города с уровнем земли - уничтожить город? Но можно ведь и сказать "сделать город ровным по отношению к земле"? Да, изъезжанный вопрос, но хотелось бы разобраться в нем детальнее.

Comment: Повтор вопроса. https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/36226/%d0%a1%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%bd%d1%8f%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81-%d0%b7%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b9-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d1%81%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bd%d1%8f%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81-%d0%b7%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b9

Answer (score 1):

Правильно:

***Сровнять с землëй.***

Корень -РОВН- обозначает **ровность** чего-либо, а -РАВН- — **равность** с чем-либо.

Примеры:

*Ровная дорога*,

*Равные треугольники*.

То есть здесь имеется в виду, что какой-то предмет, к которому используется этот фразеологизм, будет на уровне земли, то есть ровный, как земля. Так что правильно использовать корень **-РОВН-**.